# Call returns with in 2 mins without completing the operation

Tags: wcf

We have developed a web application. In it we call a WCF web service method. The WCF function will take 5 mins to generate the output. In this case, our web application returned from WCF call within 2 mins without completing the operation.

Web application web.config:

```
receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It would be much easier and more inviting to help if you'd add some more details: what the error message is, what you've researched, what you've tried to fix it, some code to reproduce the issue, etc.

Comment: Do you have the same timeouts set on the client? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is another setting in your config file that controls the http request time out's.
the default value is 110 seconds

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2008/03/10/why-changing-sendtimeout-does-not-help-for-hosted-wcf-services.aspx